Exercise 4.1.4 in vershynin's textbook: equivalent statement about isometry of matrix
I am working on the following Exercise 4.1.4 in vershynin's textbook. Recall that $A$ can be represented using the singular value decomposition, which we can write as
\begin{equation}
    A=\sum_{i=1}^r s_iu_iv_i^T, \mbox{ where } r=rank(A),
\end{equation}
where the non-negative numbers $s_i=s_i(A)$ are the singular values of $A$, the vectors $u_i\in \mathbb{R}^m$ are the left singular vectors of $A$, and the vectors $v_i\in \mathbb{R}^n$ are the right singular vectors of $A$.

Let $A$ be an $m\times n$ matrix with $m\ge n$. Prove that the following statements are equivalent.



$A^TA=I_n$.




$P:=AA^T$ is an orthogonal projection (i.e., $P^2=P$ and the image and kernel of $P$ are orthogonal subspaces) in $\mathbb{R}^n$ onto a subspace of dimension $n$.




$A$ is an isometry, or isometric embedding of $\mathbb{R}^n$ into $\mathbb{R}^m$, which means that
$$\|Ax\|_2=\|x\|_2 \mbox{ for all } x\in \mathbb{R}^n.$$



4.All singular values of $A$ equal $1$; equivalent, $s_n(A)=s_1(A)=1$.

My proof is as follows:
$1\Rightarrow 2$. Clearly, we have $P^2=(A^TA)(A^TA)=A^T(AA^T)A=A^TI_nA=A^TA=P$.
For any $x\in \mathbb{R}^m$, we write $x=Px+(I_n-P)x$. Since we have $P(x-Px)=Px-P^2x=Px-Px=0$, then $(I_n-P)x\in \ker(P)$. Note that
$$Px\cdot (I_n-P)x=x \cdot P^T(I_n-P)x=x\cdot (P^T-P^TP)x=0.$$
So the image and kernel of $P$ are orthogonal subspaces.
Question 1: does it look good for the orthogonal part?
$2\Rightarrow 3$. Note that
$$\|Ax\|_2^2=Ax\cdot Ax=x\cdot A^TAx=x\cdot x=\|x\|_2^2.$$
$3\Rightarrow 4$. Since for all $x\in \mathbb{R}^n\setminus \{0\}$, $\frac{\|Ax\|_2}{\|x\|_2}=1$. Then we have $\|A\|=\sup_{x\neq 0} \frac{\|Ax\|_2}{\|x\|_2}=1$. So we have $s_1(A)=1$.
Question 2: does this part look good for $\|A\|=1$? But how to prove other singular values must be $1$?
$4\Rightarrow 1$. Since all singular values of $A$ equal $1$, then all eigenvalues of $A^TA$ are equal $1$. By eigendecomposition of $A^TA$, there exists orthogonal matrix $O$ so that $A^TA=OI_nO^{-1}=I_n$.
Question 3: does it look good?
